# In Salesforce Post Chat getting refused to connect error

Tags: salesforce, chatbot, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities

We have added a post-chat survey to a chat window that's added to a community or a website.
But when I am ending the chat and clicking on give feedback button I am getting below msg- mydomain.force.com refused to connect.
When I am replicating the error then in browser console I am getting below error --
Refused to frame 'https://mydomain.force.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".

Comment: FYI, you might get quicker responses if you post it on the https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/ site instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check another similar question [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/289106/content-security-policy-in-embedded-services-post-chat-vf-page/367021#367021)

Yup, we've had the same issue.
The solution is to go to the `Site` page in Salesforce (Setup > Develop > Sites) and then add a `Trusted Domains for Inline Frames`.

Make sure you verify your `Clickjack Protection Level` too. A value of `Allow framing of site pages on external domains (Good protection)` or lower will work.